# Javascript module pattern, scope and "this"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around building a custom JavaScript library. I've read a lot about the module pattern, and also read Crockford's articles on private and public members. I know what is an immediately invoked function expression and why we do stuff like

```
var myLib = (function() {
}())
```

However, I'm still a little lost in some cases regarding scope and closures in general. The concrete problem I have is:

Why does the following example alert DOMWindow, rather than the myLib object?
http://jsfiddle.net/slavo/xNJtW/1/

It would be great if you can explain what "this" refers to in all of the methods in that example and why.

Comment: FYI: `this` has nothing to do with variable scope. It has only to do with the calling context of the function. Its value depends on *how* the function is called.

Comment: BTW, you can `"use strict"` in order to make the "this" in this kind of situation be undefined instead of being the window. It can help a lot to have this kind of error show up more explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside any function declared (anywhere) and invoked as follows `this` will be window object

```
function anyFunc(){
    alert(this);  // window object
}

anyFunc();


var anyFunc2 = function(){
    alert(this);  // window object
}

anyFunc2();
```

If you want to create private functions and access the instance of 'myObject' you can follow either of the following methods

One

```
module = (function () {

    var privateFunc = function() {
        alert(this);
    }

    var myObject = {
        publicMethod: function() {
            privateFunc.apply(this); // or privateFunc.call(this);
        }
    };

    return myObject;
}());


module.publicMethod();
```

Two

```
module = (function () {

    var _this; // proxy variable for instance

    var privateFunc = function() {
        alert(_this);
    }

    var myObject = {
        publicMethod: function() {
            privateFunc();
        }
    };
    _this = myObject;
    return myObject;
}());


module.publicMethod();
```

These are solutions to your issue. I would recommend using prototype based objects.

EDIT:

You can use the first method.

In fact here `myObject` is in the same scope as `privateFunc` and you can directly use it inside the function

```
 var privateFunc = function() {
     alert(myObject);
 }
```

The real scenario were you can use a proxy for `this` is shown below. You can use `call` also.

```
Module = function () {

    var _this; // proxy variable for instance

    var privateFunc = function() {
        alert(this + "," + _this);
    }

    this.publicMethod = function() {
        privateFunc(); // alerts [object Window],[object Object]
        privateFunc.call(this); // alerts [object Object],[object Object]
    }

    _this = this;
    return this;
};

var module = new Module();
module.publicMethod();
```

Comment: Why create `_this`? Inside an object, `this` should refer to that object when called like `obj.foo()`

Comment: Answer is in your question - "inside object" . Here you can see that `privateFunc` is not inside `myObject`, means not defined as a function of `myObject`. So we have to use a proxy variable.

Comment: In all functions of `myObject`, `this` will be `myObject` when invoked using dot operator - e.g: `myObject.publicMethod();`

Comment: Great. I also saw Crockford was using a proxy, he just called it "that". Didn't quite understand the concept. Which method of the two would you recommend personally, and which one is more widely used?

Comment: You can also now use arrow functions to achieve the same thing `() => this`

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state that myPrivateMethod is a member of myLib:

```
function MyLib ()
{
    this._myPrivateField = "private";
    this._myPrivateMEthod = function ()
    { 
         alert(this); // Alerts MyLib function;
    }
}

var libObject = new MyLib();
```

Just remember that without using enclosure techniques, nothing in JavaScript is ever truly private!

A better way to do the above is like so:

```
function MyLib(instanceName)
{
    this.name = instanceName;
}

MyLib.prototype.myPrivateFunction()
{
    alert(this);
}
```

To call your method after that:

```
var libObject = new MyLib();
libObject.myPrivateMethod(); // Alerts info about libObject.
```

Comment: In this case, how can I call the private method from the public methods (members of the returned object in my sample)?

Comment: Why is it better to use the latter?

Comment: Sorry. Editing the above to include!

Comment: @tandu: check out this thread. It's a pretty well done guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

The thing to remember about the module pattern is that it runs once and completes. The methods that are still available to be called are the closures. At the time of creating module, "this" refered to the window and was replaced by its value.

Answer (score -2):

In your linked fiddle, the "this" keyword is never changed by a "new" keyword or other context change, so it still refers to the global window object.

edit: clarification

Comment: *'"this" is never changed by a "new" keyword ... so it refers to the global window object.'* Completely wrong.

Comment: @amnotiam can you explain how/why it is wrong? i would like to learn something instead of just being insulted :P

Comment: *"the "this" is never changed by a "new" keyword..."* Remove the word "never" and replace it with "always". *"...or other scope change..."* `new` doesn't cause a scope change. It causes a calling context (`this`) change. *"...so it refers to the global window object."* When does `this` refer to the global window object? When using `new`? In that case it will never refer to the global. Other than that, it will depend on how the function is invoked. Sorry if you felt insulted.

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is coming from... I meant that in the fiddle he posted the "this" is still referring to the window object because he did not invoke his function as a constructor (via new). I think we are saying the same thing, I just worded it poorly.

Comment: Update your answer, and I'll remove the DV.